# Using Abel's Theorem show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\log 2$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, alternative-proof

If the question were $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\log 2$

I would do it like this $\log(1+ z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^n$ and since the series $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges, it follows by Abel's Theorem that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \lim_{r \to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}r^n = \lim_{r \to 1^-} \log(1+r)=\log 2$

Would be correct?

Is it possible that there was a typo in the question? If not, the first term would go to infinity, right?

Anyway, I'm confused.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is a typo. The summation starts at $n=1$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you

Comment: As already has been said by Gary, apart from the typo in the title, your analysis is correct.